# Who can explain the pun/wordplay on “onitada” in the story “Jaku-Chara Tomozaki-kun”

Tags: manga, anime, puns

In the Light novel / Manga / anime : 弱キャラ友崎くん (Jaku-Chara Tomozaki-kun), the main heroine regularly says “ONItada !” (translated by “HEXactly !”).

What would be the “de-pun-ed” word or how (from what words) is that word built ?

EDIT : to make myself clear, I'm mainly interested in a lexical answer (even if the syntactic and contextual aspects are also interesting)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since the question was explicitly asked to be more about the lexical construction than about other considerations, and that the other answer eludes that point. Here what I wanted to accept :

It is built as the abbreviated composition from 鬼(oni)+正しい(tadashii) ⇒ 鬼正 (onitada). for more considerations about the meaning and using context, see [Naruto's answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/86850/27954).

Comment: I failed to see what value this self-reply adds to what was already explained in naruto’s answer. It clearly says おにただ is an abbreviation of 鬼のごとく正しい. It is a fact in this light novel/nanga/anime that the silly phrase in question came from 鬼のごとく正しい.

Comment: Naruto's reply said what is said in the manga. Then, he added other very interesting complementary things - but this was not what I was looking for. The point is, I had a hard time making the link between the explanations in the manga and what I was really looking for (not the long formula, but the short lexical decomposition 鬼(oni)+正しい(tadashii) ). I would really have been glad to add that to Naruto's reply, but it looks like my request was rejected. So I had no other choice than to make myself the answer to my question as I asked it (insisting first one the pure lexical decomposition).

Comment: Explained another way : 鬼のごとく正しい is a syntactically correct proposition, but のごとく is a reconstruction not present in 鬼正, which might as well be written with other words. We might say it is syntactic sugar. It's very interesting, but it's not what I was looking for when I precised that I wished a *lexical* answer. That's why I used the word de-pun-ed : I really wanted the simple lexical decomposition, and that was missing in Naruto Answer. That why I couldn't accept it as THE answer - even though it's very good and really helped me (especially the second link).

Comment: おにただ was formed as an abbreviation of 鬼のごとく正しい in that manga. おに and ただ were taken out and then combined. That’s how the phrase was formed. It is a fact naruto has no control over. のごとく is not a reconstruction. It was part of the original phrase. As naruto’s answer clearly says, おにただ is not a generally accepted phrase. You asked about a specific phrase used in a particular manga and you got a complete answer. You *lexical* analysis is something you made up to satisfy yourself.

Comment: I didn't ask for the phrase I could see in the manga. I asked a purely lexical explanation because I thought I thought that as in HEXactly were Hex- come instead of ex-, I thought that the ただ was the end of a word that begun kind of like おに, but that was not the case : The ただ was from ただしい. This is what I wanted to know and nothing else. The rest was interresting, but it was not the answer to my question.

Comment: It is an abbreviation of 鬼のごとく正しい. The noun 鬼 and the initial part of the adjective 正しい were taken out and then combined. That’s the lexical explanation. In case you didn’t get the meaning of the original phrase, it is also explained in naruto’s answer.

Comment: Yes but that's not what I asked. I just wanted to know what word this ただ came from. Too much info hides the info.

Comment: It came from 正しい, of course. Where would it have come from when おにただ is an abbreviation of 鬼のごとく正しい? If you didn’t know how to read 正しい, the problem was in you, not in naruto’s answer.

Comment: So what ? Why do you think people ask questions if not because the problem is in their own knowledge ? I wanted an answer which would help people with the same problem. I never said Naruto's answer was wrong. On the contrary, it was very good. However, it wasn't adapted to my question and I had to search in his source to understand the missing part. That's all.

Comment: If the problem was in your failure to read 正しい as ただしい, there were appropriate ways to solve it, like looking it up in a dictionary. Denying someone’s complete answer from which you clearly benefited is not the way.

Comment: Have you already tried to find a word in a dictionary when you believe you lack its beginning ?  But there are other ways and I have searched before I asked. And by the way, I asked him twice to make his answer more adapted to the question : once in comments and once by proposing an edit, and I would gladly have given  him the answer if he had taken account of what I asked... Well, I suggest we stop here because It looks like you're taking things quite personally and this is not a chat.

Comment: So that was the problem and you were barking up the wrong tree. I got it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a pun. According to sources, it's abbreviated 鬼のごとく正しい ("correct like an *oni*", "demonically correct"). It's not a set phrase ordinary people recognize. The heroine somehow liked this funny phrase after seeing it somewhere, and started using it as a pet phrase.

I have no idea where that HEX in the English translation came from.

See: https://rightnonel.com/archives/760

鬼 can be used as a prefix meaning "super-" (e.g. 鬼かわいい, 鬼やばい). Although it's uncommon and slangy, young native speakers who are good at slang should be able to intuit the meaning of おにただ without explanation. See: https://gamp.ameblo.jp/wasansensei/entry-12592348963.html

Comment: It seems strange that there wouldn't be any pun at all, because then most people (who are not familiar with the unabnreviated form), just wouldn't understand it at all. Your second source is more explicit about this slang usage : “qualifier” becomes “oni+qualif”. So the "pun" would be “tadashii” (正しい) becomes “oni+tada” (鬼正). Your answer might be more complete by adding that.

Comment: @Camion What you're describing there is fine, but it's not what a pun is about.  I don't think most people need to understand where these sorts of expressions come from to understand that it's just a fun, quirky expression.  Folks do this all the time.  I have a friend who whenever we get together or call each other on the phone and then are going to go our separate ways, one says "shang-a-lang" and the other responds "ding-dong".  No pun,  Just being silly.  We've been doing this for over 30 years.  How this came about, I don't recall.  You could likewise think of 鬼ただ similarly.

Comment: @Camion You seem to have a different idea about the meaning of "pun" than I do. I think あけおめ, たなぼた, LOL, GIYF and so on are abbreviations but not puns.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, but i'm not a native English speaker. So I may have misused the word “pun” on something which was not designed to be funny, but still, the essence of my question was about how word were played with, even if it's not funny (I don't know if there is another word to express that in English.

Comment: @Camion おにただ *is* intended to be humorous, and it *can* be called a successful wordplay. But not all wordplays are puns.

Comment: I don't know the difference between wordplay and pun. Up to now, i thought wordplay was just a bad translation for "jeu de mot" in French.

Comment: Ok, it's not a pun because there is no multiple meanings : https://www.askdifference.com/wordplay-vs-pun/... I will modify the question.

Comment: @Camion Not to beat a dead horse.  While おにただ is not a pun itself, the English rendering *hexactly* is since to the ear there is little to distinguish *hexactly* from *exactly*.  So it is a pun in the sense of close homophony of the two words.  In written form, the word play is much more obvious.  *Hex* jumps out at you.  I always marvel at how incredibly clever many of these translations are (particularly, IMHO, when translations of literature from Japanese to English can at times be excruciatingly painful and disheartening when you're aware of the beauty of the original in Japanese).

Comment: Yeah, but that's the Japanese version i'm interested in ;-). One could say that “Devily true” might have been or more accurate translation. (the problem being as always, to know is you want a source or target oriented translation.